# Uninstalled Tor Browser and now can't open Software Updater, Synaptic Package Manager, apt; more

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, tor

I was having problems with Tor Browser and uninstalled it. Now Software Updater and Synaptic Package Manager won't open.

Synaptic  displays the following:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg

E: The list of sources could not be read.

E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Just discovered if I try to run apt I get the same message.

And software center won't open.

I probably made the original installation using Ubuntu's Software Center app. I read later on the Tor Project site that they recommended using their command line installation, which I did (I believe I uninstalled the original install first using the Software app again).

I don't know what kicked off this problem, but after it started I did go to the Tor Project and followed their instructions to remove Tor Browser -- which recommended just removing the Tor Browser directory, which I did. Doing so didn't repair anything.

Most programs work fine, but anything having to do with packages appears to be affected.

How can I get things back to normal?

**Here are the requested outputs:**

```
~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.



~$ ls -lah /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

total 48K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 27 23:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K May 14 01:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27 23:56 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  239 Oct 27 23:09 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27 23:56 cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   52 Oct 27 23:56 surfshark.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   52 Oct 27 23:09 surfshark.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   52 Oct 27 23:56 surfshark.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  234 Oct 27 23:56 tor.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  234 Oct 27 23:09 tor.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  234 Oct 27 23:56 tor.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  131 Oct 27 23:56 tor-project.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  131 Oct 27 23:56 tor-project.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27 23:56 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140 Oct 27 23:09 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27 23:56 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 23 17:36 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 23 17:36 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-jammy.list.save



~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu/ impish main # disabled on upgrade to impish
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu/ impish main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu/ hirsute main
deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main
deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main
deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main
deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jammy main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yann1ck/onedrive/ubuntu/ impish main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yann1ck/onedrive/ubuntu/ impish main


~$ sudo apt update

[sudo] password for peter: 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: What command was used to install Tor and what command did you use to remove it? Please edit the question and ad this info.

Comment: I've added the information. I hope it helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of 1) `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, 2) `ls -lah /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, 3) `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, and 4) `sudo apt update`

Comment: I should probably mention that this is a dual-boot machine with Windows 10. Don't know if that will change anything, but there it is.

Comment: Has anybody got an idea of how I can repair this?

Comment: Do I need to re-submit my original question with the requested edits to get any help on my problem? Is there some submission protocol that I'm not aware of? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Surely there's someone out there in Ubuntu-Land who can give me some guidance on this problem. Maybe?
Apparently not.
Oh, well.....

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27 23:56 yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list`

Whilst this is not related to your issue - you are using a 100% obsolete and unsupported OneDrive Client repository. The 'yann1ck' repository was obsoleted over 12 months ago.

Please follow the correct process to install the OneDrive Client for Linux: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md